# How to get a google form to spit out two lines into the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to use a google form to record the delivery of stock to a warehouse. I need it to split the different items received into separate lines in the workbook. There may be up to 5 separate items received in one delivery and my team will get jack of the process if they have to enter the first couple of questions of the form 5 times. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const lsh = e.range.getSheet();//the linked sheet
  const hs = lsh.getRange(1,1,1,lsh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//the output sheet
  let o = e.values.map((r,i) => [hs[i],r])
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm fairly novice when it comes to scripts and don't really know what to do with it. I have opened script editor and pasted it in... but don't know what to do next.

Comment: You create an onFormSubmit trigger named onMyFormSubmit() and you save the script in your script edit. You change Sheet0 to the name of your output sheet and then you go to whatever sheet you had intended to go to and begin your editing proceess and watch to see what happens